# What percentage of Earth's surface is arid?

Tags: climate, geography, climatology, desert

Is there available information on how much of Earth surface is arid climate?

Comment: I'm glad you liked the answer. However, I wonder How the question you mention would be answering your question?

Comment: May be I wronly assumed that by "dry land" he meant "arid" ? Did he just mean "land"?

Comment: I see. Yes, I think that question refers just to land, or in other words: Earth's surface not covered by water.

Comment: It would be desirable if you edit your question accordingly, to do not mislead others that might end up here looking for the same answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It will depend on the exact definition of "arid" and the period of time. But using the widely used and accepted [Köppen climate classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6ppen_climate_classification), "arid" would correspond to the four climates in [climatic group B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6ppen_climate_classification#Group_B:_Dry_(desert_and_semi-arid)_climates): "**Dry (desert and semi-arid) climates**". Using [the most up-to-date present climate data (2006)](http://koeppen-geiger.vu-wien.ac.at/present.htm) provided by the [WORLD MAPS OF KÖPPEN-GEIGER CLIMATE CLASSIFICATION](http://koeppen-geiger.vu-wien.ac.at/) at 0.5° of resolution, that looks like this (in an equal area projection):

[image]

We get that the four arid climates (group B), add up to $4.401 \times 
 10^7 {km}^2$ of a total of $1.527 \times 
 10^8 {km}^2$ inventoried in the dataset (A good match for the figure of of [global land area of $1.489 \times 10^8 km^2$ listed by wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth)), leading to a grand total of **28.8% of Earth's land surface corresponding to arid climates**.

Comment: I'd think perhaps that number is a bit high, owing to the coarse resolution.  E.g. the northeastern part of Africa has the non-arid Nile valley & delta, which is too small to show up on the map.

Comment: @jamesqf I guess ~50 km resolution is more than enough to identify climates, anything smaller would be most likely a microclimate. And in any case. Why coarser resolution would bias to higher values for arid areas? Arguable, also small arid areas would be missing.

Comment: I think it depends on exactly what the OP is asking for.  There are areas (I live in one) which are arid if considered from a climate perspective - that is, very little rainfall - but which have non-arid climate vegetation due to water from streams and/or aquifers.  Those zones are often long & narrow, like the Nile valley or the areas on the leeward sides of mountain ranges, so averaging over a coarse grid misses them.

Comment: @jamesqf Well, that's what I meant by "It will depend on the exact definition of arid", I took common definition of arid as given by the Köppen classification, which doesn't consider vegetation type. Of course, with a different classification the answer would be different. But, as the OP didn't pointed any specifics I guessed he did not care on those subtleties. And instead of specifying a definition of arid he went on to accept the answer, so I guess it was OK. But you are right in the sense that the answer depends on the climate classification used (as I stated at the start of the answer).

Answer (score 3):

[ARID LANDS: CHALLENGES AND HOPES](https://docsbay.net/arid-lands-challenges-and-hopes) *by* EARTH SYSTEM: HISTORY AND NATURAL VARIABILITY – Vol. III - *Arid Lands: Challenges and Hopes - Barakat H.N.*

> Hyperarid zones cover 7.5% of Earth's land surface, arid zones cover
>   12.1%, while semiarid zones are more extensive, occur in all continents, and cover 17.7% of Earth's land surface. The dry subhumid
>   category covers 9.9% of Earth's land surface.